# How to cast UserDetails in Spring Security context?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a class Customer class like this

```
public class MyCustomer {
   public String username;
   public String email;
   public String password;
}
```

and I have a class service which is implement UserDetailsService

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
          throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException
{
   MyCustomer customer = customerDao.findByName(username);
   return new User(customer.getName(), customer.getEmail(), true, true, true, true, customer.getRoles())
}
```

How can I get MyCustomer in the controller class? I have tried this but unfortunately, it doesnt work.

```
MyCustomer customer = (MyCustomer)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work since `User` can't be cast to `MyCustomer`.

Instead of creating a `User` instance, you can let your `MyCustomer` class implement `UserDetails` interface.

```java
public class MyCustomer implements UserDetails {
    // implementation of UserDetails methods
}
```

Then you simply return `MyCustomer` instance from your UserDetailsService.